# Script to check if users are running processes on a server

Tags: server, ssh, ps

During my Lab's Machine Learning Server maintenance I need to reboot it some times. The students using the server connect via SSH, run their jobs using NOHUP and then disconnect, leaving their jobs running. I need a way to check if non-system users are running anything before I reboot the server. The way I do it today is to fire up `htop` and then press the `u` key and then look for non-system users to see if anyone is running anything.